# How to use ModelMapper When Same Type object lists present in DTOs

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, modelmapper

I have the below Models.

**Organization Model**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table()
@JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id" )
public class Organization implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
     private Long id;

     private String name;
     .
     .
     .

     @OneToMany( mappedBy = "organization", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = User.class )
     private Set< User > users;
}
```

**User Model**

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table( name = RelationsConstant.TBL_USER_AUTH )
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    .
    .
    .
    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Organization.class )
    @JoinColumn( nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = org_usr_fk ) )
    private Organization organization;

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE )
    @JoinTable( name = RelationsConstant.TBL_USER_AUTH_ROLE, //
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "base_user_id", referencedColumnName = "base_user_id", nullable = false ), //
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false ), //
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "base_user_id", "role_id" } ) } )
    private Set< Role > roles;

}
```

**Organization DTO**

```
@Data
public class OrganizationDto implements Serializable {
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private Set<UserDto> users;
}
```

**User DTO**

```
@Data
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private OrganizationDto organization;
     private Set<RoleDto> roles;
}
```

When I try to map these models to DTOs, I get the below error.

*An error occured while processing the request org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:\r\n\r\n1) Error mapping Organization to OrganizationDto.*

**Below is the converter I used.**

```
public class SetUserToSetUserDtoConverter implements Converter< Set< User >, Set< UserDto > > {

    @Override
    public Set< UserDto > convert( MappingContext< Set< User >, Set< UserDto > > context ) {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper( );

        TypeMap< User, UserDto > propertyMapper = mapper.createTypeMap( User.class, UserDto.class );
        propertyMapper.addMappings( mpr -> {
            mpr.skip( User::getOrganization, UserDto::setOrganization );
            mpr.skip( User::getRoles, UserDto::setRoles );
            mpr.skip( User::getPrivileges, UserDto::setPrivileges );
            mpr.skip( User::getPassword, UserDto::setPassword );
        } );

        Set< User > source = context.getSource( );

        return source.stream( ).map( m -> mapper.map( m, UserDto.class ) ).collect( Collectors.toSet( ) );
    }

}
```

**This is how the mapper is configured.**

```
public List< OrganizationDto > getAll() {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper( );
    mapper.getConfiguration( ).setMatchingStrategy( MatchingStrategies.STRICT ).setFieldMatchingEnabled( true ).setFieldAccessLevel( Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE );

    /** With Converter **/
    TypeMap< Organization, OrganizationDto > typeMap = mapper.createTypeMap( Organization.class, OrganizationDto.class );

    typeMap.addMappings( mpr -> mpr.using( new SetUserToSetUserDtoConverter( ) ).map( Organization::getUsers, OrganizationDto::setUsers ) );

    return orgRepo.findAll( ).stream( ).map( m -> mapper.map( m, OrganizationDto.class ) ).collect( Collectors.toList( ) );
}
```

I found that when I remove **organization** field from **UserDto** class and remove the line **`mpr.skip( UserDto::setOrganization );`** from **Converter class**, this model mapping works fine.

Converter is defined to convert the User Objects Set to UserDto Objects Set and skip the conversion of OrganizationDto field.
User Objects and UserDto objects have **`Set<RoleDto> roles`** field.
The Converter skips that field without issue.

Any clue for rectifying this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code in my custom converter class (SetUserToSetUserDtoConverter class),

```
    TypeMap< UserAuth, UserAuthDto > propertyMapper = mapper.createTypeMap( UserAuth.class, UserAuthDto.class );
    propertyMapper.addMappings( mpr -> {
        mpr.skip( UserAuthDto::setOrganization );
        mpr.skip( UserAuth::getRoles, UserAuthDto::setRoles );
        mpr.skip( UserAuth::getPrivileges, UserAuthDto::setPrivileges );
        mpr.skip( UserAuth::getPassword, UserAuthDto::setPassword );
    } );
```

I used the below code to skip organization and unnecessary fields other fields.

```
PropertyMap< UserAuth, UserAuthDto > skipped = new PropertyMap< UserAuth, UserAuthDto >( ) {

                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    skip( ).setOrganization( null );
                    skip( ).setRoles( null );
                    skip( ).setPrivileges( null );
                    skip( ).setPassword( null );
                }

            };
```

First I doubt the organization field in the UserDto creates circular reference loop or something. But It seems my field skipping logic is incorrect.

The issue is now fixed.

Complete correct Converter implementation is below.

public class SetUserToSetUserDtoConverter implements Converter< Set< User >, Set< UserDto > > {

```
@Override
public Set< UserDto > convert( MappingContext< Set< User >, Set< UserDto > > context ) {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper( );
    mapper.getConfiguration( ).setMatchingStrategy( MatchingStrategies.STRICT ).setFieldMatchingEnabled( true );

    PropertyMap< User, UserDto > skipped = new PropertyMap< User, UserDto >( ) {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            skip( ).setOrganization( null );
            skip( ).setRoles( null );
            skip( ).setPrivileges( null );
            skip( ).setPassword( null );
        }

    };

    mapper.addMappings( skipped );

    Set< User > source = context.getSource( );

    return source.stream( ).map( m -> mapper.map( m, UserDto.class ) ).collect( Collectors.toSet( ) );
}
```

}

Got the idea and reference from the below nice blog published by Amy DeGregorio in 2018.
https://amydegregorio.com/2018/05/23/skipping-fields-with-modelmapper/